# How to Convert a <td></td> into <input /> onClick in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to convert `<td>MyData</td>` into `<input value="MyData" />` when I click on `<td>Edit</td>`. When I click on `<td>Edit</td>` I have the id of complete row. Actually I want to add Edit function to my code. Whenever I click on edit it should change all the `<td>MyData</td>` into input field where I can change it. Following is my code.

```
function ManagerGrid(props)
{
    function handleClick(value)
    {
        console.log(value)
    }
    const listItems = props.tasks.map((task)=>
    {
        return(
            <tr key={task._id}>
                <td>{task._id}</td>
                <td>{task.title}</td>
                <td>{task.detail}</td>
                <td>{task.assignee}</td>
                <td>{task.time}</td>
                <td onClick={(e)=>{handleClick(task._id)}}>Edit</td>
            </tr>
        )
    })


    return(
        <table id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Detail</th>
                    <th>Assignee</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {listItems}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your render code needs to chnage based on its current state, i.e. editing or not editing.  You need an isEditing state.  Here's an example, you'll have to work out how to save the changes.  This is based on hooks, but you could also pass it in with your props and keep track of it in a parent component.

```
function ManagerGrid(props)
{
    const [editingId, setEditingId] = useState(-1)
    function handleClick(value)
    {
        setEditingId(value)
        // TODO: cancel or save edits
    }
    const listItems = props.tasks.map((task)=>
    {
        if (editingId === task._id) {
        return(
            <tr key={task._id}>
                <td><input value={task._id} /></td>
                <td><input value={task.title} /></td>
                <td><input value={task.detail} /></td>
                <td><input value={task.assignee} /></td>
                <td><input value={task.time} /></td>
                <td onClick={(e)=>{handleSave(/*TODO*/)}}>Save</td>
            </tr>)
         else {
            return (<tr key={task._id}>
                <td>{task._id}</td>
                <td>{task.title}</td>
                <td>{task.detail}</td>
                <td>{task.assignee}</td>
                <td>{task.time}</td>
                <td onClick={(e)=>{handleClick(task._id)}}>Edit</td>
            </tr>)
         }
    })


    return(
        <table id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Detail</th>
                    <th>Assignee</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {listItems}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by creating custom component like this:

```
function ManagerGrid(props) {
  const [editedRowId, setEditedRowId] = useState(null);

  function handleClick(value) {
    setEditedRowId(value);
  }

  const listItems = props.tasks.map((task) => {
    const CellContent = ({ children }) => {
      const isCurrentTaskEdit = task._id === editedRowId;

      return (
        <td>
          {isCurrentTaskEdit ? (
            <input style={{ width: "50px" }} value={children} />
          ) : (
            children
          )}
        </td>
      );
    };

    return (
      <tr key={task._id}>
        <CellContent>{task._id}</CellContent>
        <CellContent>{task.title}</CellContent>
        <CellContent>{task.detail}</CellContent>
        <CellContent>{task.assignee}</CellContent>
        <CellContent>{task.time}</CellContent>
        <td
          onClick={(e) => {
            handleClick(task._id);
          }}
        >
          Edit
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of problems can usually be solved by creating smaller components:

```
const ReadListItem = ({
  task,
  onEdit
}) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{task._id}</td>
      <td>{task.title}</td>
      <td>{task.detail}</td>
      <td>{task.assignee}</td>
      <td>{task.time}</td>
      <td onClick={onEdit}>Edit</td>
    </tr>
  );
};

const EditListItem = ({
  task,
  onDone
}) => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(task.title);
  const [detail, setDetail] = useState(task.detail);
  const [assignee, setAssignee] = useState(task.assignee);
  const [time, setTime] = useState(task.time);

  const finished = useCallback(() => {
    onDone({
      _id: task._id,
      title,
      detail,
      assignee,
      time
    });
  }, [task, title, detail, assignee, time]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTitle(task.title);
    setDetail(task.detail);
    setAssignee(task.assignee);
    setTime(task.time);
  }, [task]);

  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{task._id}</td>
      <td><input type='text' value={title} onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)} /></td>
      <td><input type='text' value={detail} onChange={e => setDetail(e.target.value)} /></td>
      <td><input type='text' value={assignee} onChange={e => setAssignee(e.target.value)} /></td>
      <td><input type='text' value={time} onChange={e => setTime(e.target.value)} /></td>
      <td onClick={finished}>Done</td>
    </tr>
  );
}

const ListItem = ({
  task,
  onEdited
}) => {
  const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);

  return editing
    ? <EditListItem task={task} onDone={(item) => onEdited(item)}>
    : <ReadListItem task={task} onEdit={() => setEditing(true)} />
}
```

You could have another component for the inputs to reduce the amount of code, and could make better use of useCallback for the onChange handlers.

The usage would be a lot simpler:

```
const ManagerGrid = ({
  tasks
}) => {
  const onEdited = useCallback((task) => {
    console.log({task});
  }, []);

  return (
    <table id="myTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Detail</th>
          <th>Assignee</th>
          <th>Time</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        { tasks.map(task => <ListItem key={task._id} task={task} onEdited={onEdited} />) }
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

You need to note that I've made it so the tasks are not changed anywhere, because it could come from a data source that is considered immutable.  However, it can be handled in the final onEdited callback, where you could either modify the task list, or dispatch an action to handle it.

The useEffect inside the EditListItem is in case the task changes from outside of the component.

I think that this covers most of the things you've asked but please do add comments if there's anything I've missed.

Comment: I've not actually run this, so it might not be 100% correct and it may also be possible to merge the multiple useStates into a single state, or a useReducer

Comment: I've also deliberately not mapped the _id to an editable field, because you shouldn't really be editing IDs